# I am looking for a way to display some columns in a dataframe and hide others. I don't want to drop the columns I don't want to display

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to have a minimized version of my dataframe with certain columns not being displayed:

```
   Id   Author  Num_Post  Num_True_Label  Num_False_Label
0   1    Adams         3               2                1
1   2    James         1               1                0
2   3  Jessica         2               1                1
3   4     Mike         3               1                2
4   5     Paul         1               0                1
```

Expected output:

```
Num_True_Label  Num_False_Label
   3               2                
   1               1              
   2               1               
   3               1               
   1               0
```

Comment: The shown output columns don't match what is in your given dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just get those columns:

```
df[["Num_True_Label", "Num_False_Label"]]
```